# Refresh activity without re-opening it?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-activity

I implemented a button in my app that clears all sharedpreferences using this code:

```
context.getSharedPreferences("bifrostPrefs", 0).edit().clear().commit();
```

Now the problem is that whenever I use the button, I then need to exit the activity and re-open it to see results. I tried solving this by simply making the button re-open the activity with this code:

```
Intent reOpen = new Intent (Bifrost.this, Bifrost.class);
startActivity(reOpen);
```

My idea seemed smart until I noticed that if I re-open the activity, I then need to press the back button twice to get back to main activity. So I did some reserach and found this code:

```
finish();
startActivity(getIntent());
```

This now works fine, the activity gets refreshed and then I only need to click the back button once. But is there another way to refresh activity without it "flashing" in and out? As you know, everytime you open a new activity, it flashes in and out so the app lags for a second. Is there a way to refresh an activity by bypassing this?

Comment: pass intent without animation

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Well, it would be better to update the content of the activity, but if it's too complicated you can override the default animation with this method :

```
finish();
overridePendingTransition( 0, 0);
startActivity(getIntent());
overridePendingTransition( 0, 0);
```

Comment: Yes! This is exactly what I was looking for, the app works as I intended now, no need for further complications. Thank you!

Comment: where we should place this code? I put this code on needed activity, but its not working. Please help

Answer (score 2):

You can add the flag `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION` ([link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION)) to your `reOpen` intent to eleminate all animations. But as stated from the other answer better refresh the data inside you `Activity`.

Answer (score 1):

do you have some views that may change their value/size based on values from your shared preferences? if yes, create a method that init the views and call that methon on onCreate() method and in onClick() method.