# No animation on Main Activity reload

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm working in a WebView app. I have a fragment("NoInternet") that show a message: "No Internet" and when i pull down to refresh, it reload the Main Activity The Main Activity have a code to check internet conection, if don't have internet connection, it will load the fragment "NoInternet.java". If have internet, it will load another fragment with the WebView. So, in the "NoIternet" fragment, i have a SwypeRefreshLayout, that finish my MainActivity, and load it again. But it have a animation, and i don't want this animation. I tried some codes like `startActivity(new Intent(getContext(), MainActivity.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION));` but nothen work. Anyone can help me ?

NoInternet Fragment

```
SwipeRefreshLayout mySwipeRefreshLayout;

public static NoInternet newInstance() {
    NoInternet fragment = new NoInternet();
    return fragment;
}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.nointernet, container, false);
    mySwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.swiperefreshnointernet);


    mySwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            getActivity().finish();
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            mySwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think its better that you just update the content from the activity then finish it. But if you really need to do it you can try the Stephane Mathis approach from this thread: [Refresh activity without re-opening it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17488766/refresh-activity-without-re-opening-it)

```
finish();
overridePendingTransition( 0, 0);
startActivity(getIntent());
overridePendingTransition( 0, 0);
```

Comment: I'm getting errors when i put this code in my onRefresh. The errors are in "overridePendingTransition" and "getIntent"